# How to get the VertexWeight list or EdgeCapacity list in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching

The graph of `Mathematica`.We have `VertexList` or `EdgeList`.So we can get it convenient like this

```
VertexList@Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}]
```

> {a, b, c}

But not a Weight list.So I try to get it:

```
VertexWeight /. 
 Cases[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
   VertexWeight -> {2, 3, 4}], _Rule, Infinity]
```

But I get nothing but a error information.So any elegant method to do this?

Comment: `Graph` is atomic, therefore pattern matching *inside it* will not work. This is the meaning of the third point in the documentation of `Graph`, "Details and Options" section: "Graph is treated as a raw object by functions like AtomQ, and for purposes of pattern matching".

Comment: @MarcoB Oh,your explanation is a very usefull to me.Thank you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PropertyValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html) will do that for you:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]

(* Out: {2, 3, 4} *)
```

`PropertyValue[graph, EdgeWeight]` works for **edge weights** too:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}]
PropertyValue[%, EdgeWeight]

(* Out: {2, 3, 4} *)
```

Of course it also works when both properties are present, and also on individual vertices / edges:

```
g = Graph[
     {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
     VertexWeight -> {20, 30, 40}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}
    ];

PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]         (* Out: {2, 3, 4} *)
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]       (* Out: {20, 30, 40} *)

PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexWeight]  (* Out: 40 *)
```